# How to resolve secure-file-priv while importing data file in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and trying to run following query through PHP:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/usersdev/b1d/recept/rfr/Fichier_groupes_four' REPLACE INTO TABLE groupeFourTemp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' (@code, @lib) SET code = trim(@code), libelle= trim(@lib);
```

However, it is giving me an error as:
MySQL can't use "LOAD DATA INFILE", secure-file-priv option is preventing execution.

I tried using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE as well but no luck.

Also, I don't have access to my.ini, so I can't make any changes in my.ini.

Please help me out. How can I resolve this error?

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: You must get `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` and use obtained path while save and load the file.

Comment: It is showing null

Comment: In such case `LOAD DATA INFILE` operation is disabled and cannot be performed at all. If you have no access to .INI you can do nothing. Parse the file and insert data record-by-record.